# Can using OpenGL for my QGraphicsItems speed up display in my QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am using a QGraphicsView with hundreds of large QGraphicsItems in them. The QGraphicsItems are essentially QGraphicsPixmapItems because I am reading some raw data in from a file, and converting that into a QImage and then using the drawImage() painter.

The problem is, after I start getting a certain number of these items in my scene, OR just a single, very large one, the scene becomes really slow to respond. If I move the items, or try to zoom in/out on them, etc, the scene just takes forever to refresh. I would like it to be more interactive, instead of constantly waiting on the scene to refresh once all the data is loaded.

Can OpenGL help me here? How would I go about doing this? Creating a 2D rectangle and painting a texture of my raw data on it? I have all of my QGraphicsItems in a QGraphicsItemGroup, with them essentially making up one large image. If I am zoomed out far enough to see all of my hundreds of QGraphicsItems, the big "image" of the tiles is at least 32000x32000 pixels. Can OpenGL even handle that if I were mapping these as textures on rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

A texture 32000 square is 1Gpixel.  With RGBA color, that's 4GB of video memory.

You said your dimensions are even more than that, so do you have enough video RAM?  Don't forget to include space for mipmap levels.

You could probably speed this up with careful use of OpenGL, but you're going to need to manage textures intelligently and not expect OpenGL to create a texture that large.

Comment: Well, luckily it is single-band data. I guess I can put limits on how far out a user can zoom, based on how much video memory they have? The only alternate solution I could come up with is creating level of detail mapping to reduce the amount of data needed when viewing larger areas

Comment: @Derek: When zoomed in, you'll want to split the large collage into tiles and render only the ones on or immediately adjacent to the screen.  When the user pans, you've hopefully have enough time to render the next strip before it becomes visible.  Tiles leaving the area of interest can either be discarded or moved to main system memory.  And yes, you'll want to adjust the detail level when zooming out.  That's the basic idea behind mipmaps: store the image scaled to different sizes so it doesn't have to be scaled much during live rendering.

Comment: Is there a way to set the level of detail to a lesser amount automatically using QPainter, or do I have to have my own algorithm prepare a lower-detail image?

Comment: @Derek: I have no idea about Qt, I'm giving OpenGL advice since it seemed like you wanted to use it for rendering instead.  You can almost certainly find an existing algorithm with a license compatible with your software.  Search for *mipmap generation* or *image downsampling*.

Comment: Seems like my best bet is to probably install a second GPU - one for CUDA and one for display?

Comment: @Derek: I'm not sure how a second GPU would help you.  Is CUDA the primary focus of your application?  If so, it might make sense to use a different card for display.  If you're thinking of CUDA for image resampling, I'd just use OpenGL for that.  Your frame rate probably drops to 2-3/second for one frame when you resize everything, and then is back up to the full refresh rate during panning or minor zoom adjustment.

Comment: This viewer I am building has a few CUDA algorithms as plugins to it. I am using CUDA for everything else - it's just generating the pixels to be displayed. I am looking to OpenGL to help actually display those pixels faster

Comment: @Derek: I'm starting to understand.  Yes, I definitely would use OpenGL for display in this case, and not Qt painting functions.  CUDA should be able to update an OpenGL texture buffer directly and save transferring the data back to the CPU.  (Of course, OpenCL is the GPGPU language designed for cooperation with OpenGL, but I'm sure I've seen demos of CUDA doing the same).  Might make sense to do coarse scaling with a CUDA kernel, and then OpenGL just has to do panning and fine scaling, by texturing a full-window quad.